# Collections.sort() on ArrayList does not seem to correctly sort

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, floating-point, nan

I am attempting to sort an ArrayList of TokenDoubleCounters (my custom object). In TokenDoubleCounter, I have implemented equals and compareTo as below:

```
public class TokenDoubleCounter implements Comparable<TokenDoubleCounter> {
private String word;
private double count;

public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof TokenDoubleCounter) {
        TokenDoubleCounter other = (TokenDoubleCounter) o;
        if (other.word.equals(this.word) && other.count == this.count)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public int compareTo(TokenDoubleCounter other) {
    double result = this.count - other.getCount();
    if (result > 0.0) 
        return 1;
    if (result < 0.0) 
        return -1;
    return this.word.compareTo(other.getWord());
}

    //rest of class omitted
}
```

These objects are created and sorted in the following function call:

```
    public List<TokenDoubleCounter> chiSquareValueAll(int cl, int cl2) {
    List<TokenDoubleCounter> list = new ArrayList<TokenDoubleCounter>();

    for (String word : map.keySet()) {
                                                        //chiSquareValue2 returns a double
        list.add(new TokenDoubleCounter(word, chiSquareValue2(cl,cl2,word)));       
    }
    Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder());
    return list;
}
```

Finally, iterating through these results, I write these to file:

```
    public boolean printChiSquare(PrintWriter out, int cl, int cl2) {
    for (TokenDoubleCounter tdc : this.chiSquareValueAll(cl,cl2)) {
        if (tdc.getCount() > 2.7) {
             //getWord() returns string value "word"  and getCount() returns double value "count"
            out.write(tdc.getWord() + "," + tdc.getCount() + "\n");

        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The results were somewhat surprising to me as they do not seem to be in the order I requested:

> word,8.937254901960785 
>   word,8.937254901960785 
>   word,8.937254901960785 
>   word,5.460792811839323 
>   word,4.746170542635659 
>   word,4.382692307692308 
>   word,4.382692307692308 
>   word,4.382692307692308 
>   word,4.382692307692308 
>   word,4.382692307692308 
>   word,4.382692307692308 
>   word,4.382692307692308 
>    **word,8.937254901960785**  
>   word,8.937254901960785 
>   word,8.937254901960785 
>   word,8.937254901960785 
>   word,8.937254901960785 
>   word,8.937254901960785 
>  
>   word,8.937254901960785 
>   word,5.460792811839323 
>   word,4.746170542635659 
>   word,4.746170542635659 
>   word,4.746170542635659 
>   word,4.382692307692308 
>  
>   ...

What am I missing? And let me know if you need additional details.

Also, I should add that all of the entries "word" are actually strings of varying length, etc., but I don't think that's relevant.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It is possible that some of your `count` values are `NaN`s.  That could screw up your sorter.

Comment: Why don't use `int java.lang.Double.compare(double d1, double d2)`?

Comment: Is the sorting correct when you do it in natural order (instead of the reverse order)?

Comment: Paul/Keith, that was the problem and solution. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public int compareTo(TokenDoubleCounter other) {
    int result = Double.compare(count, other.count);
    return result != 0 ? result : word.compareTo(other.word);
}
```

Comment: A simple test of all the double values "count" (using `Double.isNaN(double)`) showed that several NaNs were messing up the sorter. This solved my problem. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

A comparator doesn't have to return just -1, 0, 1.  You might consider having the difference between the counts be used to create a magnitude instead (if that makes sense for your data).  Then, the items should fall into place based on their relative ordering.

I think you are ending up with a bunch of items with the same comparator result and they maintain insertion order in that case.